# Bulge in infiniti q50 driver's side bridge stone

Tags: tires

So I just noticed a bulge in the tire on the driver side of my car. It is a 2015 model and it has less than 10,000 miles on it. I am wondering if I need to change this ASAP or I can drive (about a 100-120 miles) to get home and do it there.

[image]

Comment: I think I can tell where the bulge is but I'm unsure of the location and how much it bowed out.  The angle on the pic makes it hard to discern.  Can you take another an upload it?  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: FYI - There is an airbag recall for your vehicle.  Check with your local dealer to see if you VIN is affected.    https://www.cars.com/recalls/infiniti-q50-2015/

Answer (score 5):

You will run into these risks if you decide to take the car on a trip like this:

- Tire may burst at highway speeds.
- It may deflate over the time.
- Steering may become shaky, if it is the front tire.

If you still want to take the risk, I would recommend you take the following precautions:

- Drive slowly, no more than 50 mph.
- Check pressure a few times during the trip.

Otherwise, if you can go to the dealer now, just do it. It does not take that much time and you will not save too much going to another dealership and the service may still be covered under warranty.

Answer (score 2):

It's a run-flat tire, so not as bad as a normal tire, but I'd drive to nearest dealership to get their advice. I wouldn't try 100 miles on it.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments people. Went and got me a new tire. Really appreciate the responses.